# How to pass a variable in a curl command in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have a curl command:

```
curl -u ${USER_ID}:${PASSWORD} -X GET 'http://blah.gso.woo.com:8080/rest/job-execution/job-details/${job_id}'
```

The variable `job_id` has a value in it, say, 1160. When I execute the curl command in shell it gives me the following error:

```
{"message":"Sorry. An unexpected error occured.", "stacktrace":"Bad Request. The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax."}
```

If I pass the number '1160' directly in the command, as shown below, the curl command works.

```
curl -u ${USER_ID}:${PASSWORD} -X GET 'http://blah.gso.woo.com:8080/rest/job-execution/job-details/1160'
```

I want to be able to pass the value of the variable in the curl command.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

When using variables in [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), you can only use doubles quotes, not single quotes : the variables inside single quotes are not expanded.
Learn the difference between ' and " and `. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and https://web.archive.org/web/20230314111401/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: Double quotes while assigning the value 1160 to job_id? You mean like this? "job_id=1160". And then call it inside the curl command using ${job_id}?

Comment: yes : `job_id=1160; curl -u ${USER_ID}:${PASSWORD} -X GET "http://lppma670.gso.aexp.com:8080/rest/job-execution/job-details/${job_id}"`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! It works! :) I will be able to accept your answer in 5 mins. So will do that :)

Answer (score 37):

I ran into this problem with passing as well, it was solved by using ' " $1 " '

See **connection.uri** below

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '
  {"name": "mysql-atlas-sink",
   "config": {
     "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
     "tasks.max":"1",
     "topics":"mysqlstock.Stocks.StockData",
     "connection.uri":"'"$1"'",
     "database":"Stocks",
     "collection":"StockData",
     "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
     "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://schema-registry:8081",
     "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
     "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://schema-registry:8081",
     "transforms": "ExtractField",
     "transforms.ExtractField.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value",
     "transforms.ExtractField.field":"after"
}}' http://localhost:8083/connectors -w "\n"
```

Comment: I found that this approach works, but do not believe there is a need for supplemental double-quotes surrounding the environment variable.  In other words, in the above example, `'$1'` works just as well as `"'"$1"'"`.  I believe both of these approaches work by breaking the single-quoted string into two single-quoted substrings, each adjacent to the expanded `$1` environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

use variable in a double-quote single-quote "' $variable '"

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
token=xxxxxx
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8009/submit/expense/' \
        --form 'token="'$token'"' \
        --form 'text="'$1'"' \
        --form 'amount="'$2'"'
```

Answer (score 4):

How to pass [json](/questions/tagged/json) to [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) with [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) variable(s):

```
myvar=foobar
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @/dev/stdin<<EOF
{ "xkey": "$myvar" }
EOF
```

With the switch `-d` or `--data`, the **POST** request is *implicit*

Answer (score 1):

```
userdetails="$username:$apppassword"
base_url_part='https://api.XXX.org/2.0/repositories'
path="/$teamName/$repoName/downloads/$filename"
base_url="$base_url_part$path"**strong text**
curl  -L -u "$userdetails" "$base_url" -o "$downloadfilename"
```