# cURL in Bash - Passing Variables Between Single Quotes

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am trying to pass parameters to cURL through the command line, this way:

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '<Data Token="someToken" Name='"$appName"' ID='"$someVar"' ParseAppID='"$someVar"' ParseRESTKey='"$someVar"' AndroidPackage='"$someVar"' Version="1"></Data>' 'https://prefix.something.com/somePath?InputType=Xml'
```

(This line is actually extracted from the Postman app).

I Googled this issue and found whole lot of solutions that did not work for me (links are to SO past questions...):

1. I tried [isolating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash-shell-script) the variables by ending the single quotes, this way: `'before...'"${someVar}"'...after...'`. Could not complete the request.
2. I tried passing the variables [using a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514199/how-to-send-double-quote-in-d-parameter-for-curl-exe) (`-d @fileName)`. Failed to post.
3. I tried [replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341955/how-to-pass-a-variable-in-a-curl-command-in-shell-scripting) the single quotes surrounding the `<Data>` tokens  with double quotes - but the command apparently cannot accept such substitution.

The errors I get are either `<Error></Error>` or `The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.`

Is there any chance that there exists some other solution?
Has anyone encoutered such problem before?

I would be greatful for any help.

Comment: Dropping out of single quotes is the only way to get the variables to get expanded. That said whether the contents of the variables are legal in that location is a different question. You may very well construct an illegal request that way but that's not a shell variable issue. What was your exact failure when you tried that?

Comment: @EtanReisner thanks for the comment. When I do something like I do something like `'<Data Name='"$appName"'></Data>' `, the error I get is empty: `<Error></Error>`. I tried echoing the variables prior to this command, and they are all correctly printed.

Comment: Providing a way to do this where the output is guaranteed to always be valid XML, by the way, would be a different, longer answer. @chepner has the cheap/easy approach covered; ensuring document validity (entity escaping and the like) calls for different tools.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You aren't supplying quotes around the value of `ID` like you are for `Name`. That is, you need

```
'<Data Token="someToken" Name="'"$appName"'" ...>'
                              ^^^
                              |||
                              ||+- shell quote to protect $appName
                              |+- shell quote enclosing the XML
                              +- literal quote embedded in the XML
```

which results in the string (assuming `appName=foo`)

```
<Data Token="someToken" Name="foo" ...>
```

Comment: Hi @chepner and thanks. I tried applying this on all parameters like this: `curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '<Data Token="someToken" Name="'"$someVar"'" ID="'"$someVar"'" ParseAppID="'"$someVar"'" ... Version="1"></Data>' 'someURL'` and still got `<Error></Error>`. Are the changes correct?

Comment: @OphirHarpaz, if you want to know if your changes are correct, use `bash -x yourscript` to see exactly what is being passed to curl (though that's shell-escaped, as opposed to byte-for-byte). That said, on a glance, what you're doing there looks good to me -- which is to say that it should be substituting in the variables in question; whether the result is a valid document is a different discussion.

Comment: With what Charles says, I would try a sample query where you hard-code *everything* to make sure that you are getting the query correct, independent of any shell quoting.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy okay, thanks a lot. I will try that and examine if I truly pass valid parameters. Thanks again, your answers helped!