# How to generate XRay Vulnerabilties report using rest api

Tags: rest, artifactory, jfrog-xray

Could someone please help to generate Vulnerability report via REST API for artifacts?
Maybe a sample example will help.

Looked at the below documentation but not clear to me
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+REST+API#XrayRESTAPI-GenerateVulnerabilitiesReport

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Xray version is 3.x, kindly follow the below curl command which should give you the report,

```
curl -u<username>:<password> http://artifactory_URL/xray/api/v1/reports/vulnerabilities -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @report.json
```

In the report.json file, add the information which you need to generate the report for.
For example:

> cat report.json
> {

```
"name": "report1",
"resources": {
    "repositories": [
        {
            "name": "libs-release-local"
        }
    ],
    "builds": {
        "names": [
            "art-docker-test",
            "art-docker-prod"
        ]
    }
},
"filters": {
    "vulnerable_component": "*vulnerable:component*",
    "impacted_artifact": "some://impacted*artifact",
    "has_remediation": false,
    "cve": "CVE-1234-1234",
    "issue_id": "XRAY-1234",
    "severities": [
        "High",
        "Medium"
    ],
    "cvss_score": {
        "min_score": 6.3,
        "max_score": 9
    },
    "published": {
        "start": "2020-06-29T12:22:16Z",
        "end": "2020-06-29T12:22:16Z"
    },
    "scan_date": {
        "start": "2020-06-29T12:22:16Z",
        "end": "2020-06-29T12:22:16Z"}

}
```

}

I'm generating a report for the repository "libs-release-local" and build name "art-docker-test" and "art-docker-prod" with filters as you can understand.

Comment: Thanks Muhammed. Could you plz let me know how to find the issue ID.Is there any way to pass some of the above info using variables coz i want to generate report for multiple repos ..dont want to hardcode

Comment: If you are using shell script or postman then you can use variables, you can also refer to this stackoverflow for variables in curl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341955/how-to-pass-a-variable-in-a-curl-command-in-shell-scripting